# Unittesting with ASP MVC: Validator.TryValidateObject returns always true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, validation

I'm trying to validate a MVC-model with Validator.TryValidateObject. 
This works in production mode, but not in the unittest code.
Validator.TryValidateObject give me alwasy true.

The code parts:

In the Controller-Constructor, I inject the Model:

```
private IEmailModel model;  
public JoggenController(IEmailModel m)  
{  
 this.model = m;  
}
```

In the action-methode I validate the model, works fine in production mode, isValid is true or false:

```
public ViewResult AddEmail(String email)  
{  
model.Email = email;  
var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);  
var list = new List<ValidationResult>();   
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, list, true);              
 //...
```

Now I will test my AddEmail() and use this testcode:

```
var emailModel = new Mock<IEmailModel>();  
emailModel  
     .Setup(p => p.Email)  
     .Returns("xxx");  

var controller = new Controller(emailModel.Object);  

//should Faking ModelState.IsValid = false             
controller.ModelState.Add("testError", new ModelState());  
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("testError", "test");  

var result = controller.AddEmail("xxx") as ViewResult;      
//...
```

If I debug the testcode, var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject returns always true.
Whats the Problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing your model as constructor parameter to your controller? A better approach would be to have your controller action directly take the model as action parameter and have the model binder do the job instead of you manually writing plumbing validation code in your action.

Comment: I do this, because I can give r the controller a mock object of the model. So I have the controll over the used model class. That was my intention.

Comment: You could pass a repository to the controller constructor which could be mocked and then use plain POCOs for view models.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except my unit test works, and my product code doesn't :-/